Residual months not added to renewed passport. Can I do anything?
Ten years ago, when I renewed my passport, the residual ten months from the preceding one was added on to the new one.
This year, the residual eight months from the 2014 passport was not added on to the new one. I e-mailed the passport office but did not receive a reply. (I am sure that everybody knows this but; anyway, a passport becomes next-to-useless in its last six months because too many countries will not accept it--why not; what difference does it make?)
Is there anything, legally, I can actually do about this?

The main reason is that the producer's are required to insure that chips functions for a period of at least 10 years. This lead to the ICAO recommendation of a validity period of 5 to 10 years. (Doc 9303 Part 2: Specifications for the Security of the Design,
Manufacture and Issuance of MRTDs)

A lot (most?) of countries never issued passports with variable validity term in the first place. If your country did, this was an exotic practice that everyone else (border security agencies, airlines, etc...) had to deal with. The world tends to standardize on things like this.

@MarkJohnson Main reason for what? Limited validity and rules around validity on entry predate chips and biometric passports.

@fraxinus nobody has to "deal with" unusual or variable validity periods of travel documents.  They just compare the relevant dates to whatever rule they're enforcing.

Tony, did it occur to you, by any chance, that maybe the country might, just might, be relevant to your question?

This question should be edited to have a title that gives an idea what's actually being asked instead of named for a very, very broad topic. Maybe "Recourse for lost residual validity time when renewing passport?"

united-kingdom
The UK Passport Office stopped adding extra months to passports on 10 September 2018.  This was a well documented change in policy (see for example Types of British Passports).  I don't know what legal mechanism you might be able to use to try to compel the government to resume its old policy, but I doubt it would be successful.
It's worth noting that the extra months of validity would also be of limited use in some countries, including the Schengen area and all of the EU except Ireland, because third-country passports must be no older than ten years at the time of entry.

+1.  It was the behaviour of the Schengen area which caused this change: they would not recognise the validity of passports issued more than 10 years earlier, even if the expiry date had not been reached.  This led to UKPO changing its policy to reduce the number of cases of people thinking they could still use unexpired passports.

@Henry But it was only in 2021 (after the transition period ended) that this rule came into effect for UK citizens. See also 2019-11-23: ESTA with UK passport (valid > 10 years) - Travel Stack Exchange

@MarkJohnson - that is correct, though the Schengen Border Code with this ten year rule was decided in March 2016, and later realising the effect of that combined with expected Brexit (plus encouragement from ICAO) is what led UKPO to change its practice.

@Henry The ten year rule was introduced in 2013. Schengen Border Code - M5 Regulation (EU) No 610/2013 of the European Parliament and of the Council of 26 June 2013

@MarkJohnson for the sake of completeness I would note that the effective date of this change was 18 October 2013, which explains why the consolidated version reflecting the change shows that date rather than the date of adoption of the amending regulation.  This of course does not exclude the possibility that the existence of the ten-year rule was the first of two conditions leading to the passport office's change, the second being the result of the Brexit referendum in June 2016.

@phoog It should also not be excluded that automated software, such as ESTA applications, were having problems with these UK passports and lead to (or influenced) this change.

You want to protect your citizens from trying to travel with a passport that’s isn’t accepted and wasting their money. EU states don’t care how long your non-EU passport is valid, so you don’t lose anything. And you wouldn’t stop longer dated in 2021 with the result that for the next ten years people will be rejected at the border. You stop them in 2013 so people are rejected only in 2022 and 2023.

@gnasher729 I don't understand your comment.  EU states don't care about the validity period of non-EU passports, but they do refuse to allow entry to those bearing non-EU passports that were issued more than ten years previously.  The UK could not have stopped issuing such passports for that reason in 2013 because nobody knew in 2013 that UK passports would cease to be EU passports at any particular point in the future.  They stopped in 2018 because that was when they realized that this would be a problem.

I'll try to answer this part of your question:

a passport becomes next-to-useless in its last six months because too
many countries will not accept it--why not; what difference does it
make?

Chase bank has a page, "What is the 6-month passport rule?" They list 24 countries that have this rule.
Countries are much more likely to announce what a rule is than to announce an explanation of why the rule was adopted. So I'll give my own opinion of why the rule exists. A traveler might arrive in a country and intend to stay only a few days. But something might happen that delays departure, such as a serious illness or falling in love. So the country being visited want's reasonable assurance that when the traveler is finally ready to leave, the passport will still be valid and the departure will be possible.
